# "benefactor of the race"

Tags: meaning-in-context

**Sample:**

> “You reasoned it out beautifully,” I exclaimed in unfeigned admiration “It is so long a chain, and yet every link rings true.”
>
> “It saved me from ennui,” he answered, yawning. “Alas! I already feel it closing in upon me. My life is spent in one long effort to escape from the commonplaces of existence. These little problems help me to do so.”
>
> “And you are a **benefactor of the race**,” said I.

Source: The Red-headed League

**Question:**

Watson praised Holmes's way solving the case. I take the word benefactor as "helper", then could the word "race" possibly mean the "red-headed race" or "the whole human race"?

In other words, does the phrase mean:

1. a man superior to others as Holmes is very smart and has brilliant reasoning power? or
2. He is a helper of the red-headed race? or
3. He has accomplished a humanitarian act?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which race is ambiguous, but likely "the race of man" (i.e. humans), or "the English race".  A full answer might need to explain concepts of race that existed in 1890s England, because they do not closely match contemporary ideas.

Comment: It means he is valuable to other people, to the (human) race.

Answer (score 1):

Which race is ambiguous, but likely "the race of man" (i.e. humans), or "the English race". A full answer might need to explain concepts of race that existed in 1890s England, because they do not closely match contemporary ideas. –
Juhasz

Comment: I'm pretty certain that he means 'the human race'. If he had means 'the English' he would have used _nation_.